# Casting between object type of ' FileWebRequest ' to ' HttpRequest '

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Good evening guys

I'm new here in this forum, and I need you to help me

Am working on a project that send a file of XML, and I'm using HTTPRequest, I faced an error like this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.net.HTTPWebrequest'

![enter image description here][1]

```
public string POST(string URL, string MsgXML)
{
  string Response = null;
  try
  {

    Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.ContentType = "text/xml";
    byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MsgXML);
    Request.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
    Request.GetRequestStream().Close();

    using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
      StreamReader Rdr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
      Response = Rdr.ReadToEnd();
      Rdr.Close();
      Rdr = null;
      return Response;
    }
  }
}
```

And that was the method of posting I used.

And I dnt know what to do, please Help me guys :)

Answer (score 2):

From [`WebRequest.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx), which is the *actual* method you are calling (the compiler lets you get away with calling a static method "through"  a derived class):

> [..] when a URI beginning with http:// or https:// is passed in
>   requestUri, an HttpWebRequest is returned by Create. If a URI
>   beginning with ftp:// is passed instead, the Create method will return
>   a FileWebRequest instance. **If a URI beginning with file:// is passed
>   instead, the Create method will return a FileWebRequest instance.**

You have two options, basically:

1. Write your method so that it will work for any kind of URI, including file resources.
2. Validate that the string represents a URI that is a resource accessed over http (for example, with [`Uri.Scheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx)).